# How to free memory properly?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, realloc

Please help, I can't figure out how to free memory correctly. There is a code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INT_MSG_LEN 25;

enum {NO_ERROR = 0, 
      ERROR_INPUT = 100, 
      ERROR_LEN = 101};

static const char *error_texts[] = { "Error input!", 
                                     "Error lenghts!"};

void shift(char *msgEnc, char *msg, char *msgRes, char *mainMsg, char *alphabet, int offset);
void report_error(int error);
void print_error(int error);
int get_sameletters(char *msg, char *msgRes, int offset);
int get_letter(char letter, char *alphabet);
int compare(char *msgEnc, char *msg, char *msgRes, char *alphabet, int offset);
char *read_Input_Msg(int *msglen);
char rotate(char *original, int offset);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = NO_ERROR;
    char *msgEnc, *msg, alphabet[53] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int msgEncLen, msgLen;

    msgEnc = msg = NULL;
    msgEncLen = msgLen = 0;

    msgEnc = read_Input_Msg(&msgEncLen);
    if (msgEnc)
        msg = read_Input_Msg(&msgLen);

    if (msgEnc == NULL || msg == NULL)
        ret = ERROR_INPUT;
    else if (msgEncLen != msgLen)
        ret = ERROR_LEN;
    
    char msgRes[msgEncLen], mainMsg[msgEncLen];
    
    if (ret == NO_ERROR)
        shift(msgEnc, msg, msgRes, mainMsg, alphabet, msgEncLen);
    else
        print_error(ret);

    free(msgEnc);
    free(msg);
    return ret;
}

void shift(char *msgEnc, char *msg, char *msgRes, char *mainMsg, char *alphabet, int offset)
{//function for decoding text by a defined offset
    int dis;
    dis = compare(msgEnc, msg, msgRes, alphabet, offset);
    for (int i = 0; i<offset; ++i)
            mainMsg[i] = msgEnc[i]+dis;

    rotate(mainMsg, offset);
    for(int i = 0; i<offset; ++i)
        printf("%c", mainMsg[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void report_error(int error)
{//prints error 
    if (error >= ERROR_INPUT && error <= ERROR_LEN)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error_texts[error - ERROR_INPUT]);
}

void print_error(int error)
{//what error it is
    switch (error){
        case ERROR_INPUT:
            report_error(ERROR_INPUT);
            break;
        case ERROR_LEN:
            report_error(ERROR_LEN);
            break;
    }
}

int get_sameletters(char *msg, char *msgRes, int offset)
{//gets count of sameletters between two strings
    int sameLetters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<offset-1; ++i){
        if (msg[i] == msgRes[i])
            sameLetters++;
    }
    return sameLetters;
}

int get_letter(char letter, char *alphabet)
{   
    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0; alphabet[i]; ++i){
        if (letter == alphabet[i])
            k = i;
    }
    return k;
}

int compare(char *msgEnc, char *msg, char *msgRes, char *alphabet, int offset)
{//calculate a distance between first input string and string what will get after decryption
    int distance, max_letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; alphabet[i]; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; msgEnc[j]; ++j){
                msgRes[j] = alphabet[(get_letter(msgEnc[j], alphabet) + i) % 52];
            }
            int sameLetters = get_sameletters(msg, msgRes, offset);
            if (sameLetters >= max_letters){
                max_letters = sameLetters;
                distance = i;
            }
    }
    return distance;
}

char *read_Input_Msg(int *msglen)
{//input messages, at the same time counts the length of the entered string
    int capacity = INT_MSG_LEN;
    char *msg = malloc(capacity);
    int c, len = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
        if (!((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))) {
            free(msg);
            msg = NULL;
            len = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (len == capacity){
            char *tmp = realloc(msg, capacity * 2);
            if (tmp == NULL){
                free(msg);
                msg = NULL;
                len = 0;
                break;
            }
            capacity *= 2;
            msg = tmp;
        }
        msg[len++] = c;
    }
    *msglen = len;
    return msg;
}

char rotate(char *original, int offset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<offset; ++i){
        if (original[i] > 'Z' && original[i]<'a')
            original[i] += 6;
        else if (original[i] > 'z'){
            int k = (int)original[i];
            k -= 58;
            original[i] = (char)k;
        }
    }
    return *original;
}
```

`When I run it through Valgrind, it says to me that I have errors with the allocated memory, says I do not free it. Writes that memory is not freed at 107.56 and 44 lines, more precisely`

```
==56665== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==56665==    at 0x4015BF: compare (main.c:107)
==56665==    by 0x401468: shift (main.c:56)
==56665==    by 0x4012C3: main (main.c:44)
==56665== 
�elloword
==56665== 
==56665== HEAP SUMMARY:
==56665==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==56665==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,098 bytes allocated
==56665== 
==56665== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==56665== 
==56665== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==56665== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==56665== ERROR SUMMARY: 52 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems to have freed the memory, but this is not enough, because there is unfreed memory after some function calls. I guess I just don't know how to free it. At the end of each function that asks for additional memory, I tried to free it through free (the array that the function called), but in this case it displays a segmentation fault. I would be grateful if you let me know at least something.

here's example to input

```
xUbbemehbT
XYlloworld
```

Comment: You don't show the `valgrind` output that you are asking about.

Comment: Yep, just  added

Comment: What inputs you used for Valgrind to pop `memory-leaks` logs?

Comment: clang -g -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 filename.c

Comment: sample inputs for the program, that makes the program leak memory. What this program is supposed to do?

Comment: When calling your program with the posted input, the line `msgRes[j] = alphabet[(get_letter(msgEnc[j], alphabet) + i) % 52];` will invoke undefined behavior. On the 11th time that line is executed, `get_letter` will return `-1`, and because `i == 0`, you will be accessing the array `alphabet` out of bounds.

Comment: @SparKot it decrypts text using the Caesar method. First I input the text to be decoded, and the second text shows how far I need to move the letters in the first text. That is, the distance is selected at which there is more correspondence in letters between the received text and the second entered text.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I changed it, but still have that problem

Comment: It seems `read_Input_Msg` does not NUL terminate the arrays so they do not contain valid strings. Then `compare` tries to use them as strings. Add NUL termination to `read_Input_Msg`.

Comment: @kaylum Doesn't EOF just do that?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You don't store the EOF and even if you did it would be wrong as EOF is not 0. You need to have something like: `msg[len] = '\0';` after the `while` loop. You may also need `len++` - I haven't looked closely enough at the code to work out whether `len` needs to include the NUL terminator.

Comment: i added but the memory problem still remained. It seems to me that the problem is that I need to somehow free the memory after I call the functions that use these two inputs. It seems to me, but I just can't understand how to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valgrind output does **not** say that you have a memory leak or that you didn't free something properly.

If you look at this part of the output:

```
==56665== HEAP SUMMARY:
==56665==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==56665==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,098 bytes allocated
==56665== 
==56665== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

It states that all memory blocks that were allocated were freed.  So you don't have an allocation problem.

The important part is this part:

```
==56665== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==56665==    at 0x4015BF: compare (main.c:107)
==56665==    by 0x401468: shift (main.c:56)
==56665==    by 0x4012C3: main (main.c:44)
```

This says that at the `compare` function at line 107 (which was called from `shift` at line 56, which in turn was called from `main` at line 44), a value that was never initialized was read.  This line is:

```
for (int j = 0; msgEnc[j]; ++j){
```

So this tells us you're reading a byte in the `msgEnc` array that was never written to.  This array was written to in the `read_Input_Msg` function which reads one character at a time into the array.

Since this is array is supposed to be a string, and because you're reading a byte at a time, you need to manually add a terminating null byte which you're not doing.  So when `compare` is eventually called, the above line is looking for a null byte which was never explicitly written, so you end up reading uninitialized bytes.

After the main `while` loop in `read_Input_Msg`, add the null byte at the end of the string:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
    ...
}
msg[len]=0;
```

Comment: omg, thank you so much.You can’t even imagine how you saved me, I am very grateful to you for the explanation!